# accessing IMap from EntryProcessor

Tags: hazelcast

Can IMap or other Hazelcast distributed data structures like AtomicLong be accessed from within process() method of an EntryProcessor?

I'm getting following exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread[hz.Alcatraz-ANP-Sys-HAZLE-2.actiance.local.partition-operation.thread-5,5,Alcatraz-ANP-Sys-HAZLE-2.actiance.local] cannot make remote call: com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.operations.LockOperation@3229190f
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.DistributedExecutorService$CallableProcessor.run(DistributedExecutorService.java:189) ~[hazelcast-3.3_actiance.jar:3.3]
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:209) [hazelcast-3.3_actiance.jar:3.3]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76) [hazelcast-3.3_actiance.jar:3.3]
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92) [hazelcast-3.3_actiance.jar:3.3]
```

I'm using Hazelcast version 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access other datastructures but you need to make sure they're in the same data partition as the currently processed entry. This means you can use (for example) data affinity to pin all data together in the same partition.

Sharing an IAtomicLong between different partitions is not possible though.

PS: You also shouldn't mutate other data than the current processed entry since it might end up in a deadlock between different nodes.