# Hazelcast use EntryProcessor executeOnEntries to enqueue

Tags: queue, hazelcast

I'm using executeOnEntries over a map and I would like to enqueue values into a queue in it's process method.

When I try and do that I get an IllegalThreadStateException (cannot make remote call: com.hazelcast.collection.impl.queue.operations.OfferOperation)

So I guess this is why:
[accessing IMap from EntryProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898557/accessing-imap-from-entryprocessor)

Which brings me to ask if I can define some kind of 'local' queue on each of the HZ instances and listen to it from another 'global' (shared) queue ? Or solve this in some kind of other way.

Comment: Did you try Offloadable EntryProcessor? Partition operations are offloaded to a non-partition thread when implement Offloadable interface in EP. I haven’t tested this myself but I think this should allow you to access IQueue.

Comment: Thanks @wildnez

Using Offloadable & ReadOnly didn't solved my problem entirely but it was a key element. The fact that I'm using executeOnEntries is still hearting me and leads to the same outcome.
Once I've iterated over the map and used executeOnKey this worked.
Since my initial use of the EP was in a ClientListener, I've wanted my queue to only have a single copy for each map element and this is why I tried using executeOnEntries.

If I just iterate and double lock on a key checking with contains I'll still have an issue if someone removed an element from the queue while inserting.

Comment: Thats another red flag - creating EP in a client listener. You dont want to keep listener thread for long and should be looking to release the thread at the earliest possible. Otherwise, you run the risk of event queues filling up fast, resulting in events dropping out.